# TYPO3 LIMIT from flexform field

Tags: php, select, limit, typo3

I insert to flexform field `max_item_to_display` and try to get that value in my `SELECT query`:

```
$maxDisplayItem = $this->_getFlexformConfig('max_item_to_display');

$dbResource = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*',                           // SELECT
                                                     'tx_mageconnect_products',     // FROM
                                                     'product_id IN ('.implode(',',$productIds).') 
                                                        AND store_view = \''.$store.'\'
                                                        AND hidden = \'0\' 
                                                        AND deleted = \'0\'
                                                        AND pid = \''.$pid.'\'',    // WHERE
                                                     'product_id',                  // GROUP BY
                                                     '',                            // ORDER BY
                                                     '$maxDisplayItem'              // LIMIT 
                                                    );
```

The value of `max_item_to_display` is in `tt_content` table, but above code didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes when you want to have the variable-value in `'$maxDisplayItem'`

use `$maxDisplayItem` without quotes.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php